# Hi,In springMvc Rest Onetoone CRUD of client side. when i am inserting data it was working just fine and shows error while updating and deleteing

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

==>here when i want to insert data it just working fine,The Only problem is when am updating or deleting it was showing error.So, how to make it work for updating and deleting.

[CRUD IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alhIB.png)
[Error image when deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54rRB.png)
[Data base image rever engineering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kF6H.png)

```
application.properties
/***************************/
crm.rest.url=http://localhost:8080/restonetoone/api/details
```

> this Details.java is OnetoOne with Student.java (these are DTO's)

```
 Details.java
    /*******************/
    package com.rest.entity;
    
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    
    @Entity
    public class Details {
    
        @Id
        private int id;
        
        private String city;
        
        private long mobileno;
        
        @OneToOne
        private Student student;
        
        public Details(){
            
        }
    
    
        public Details(int id, String city, long mobileno, Student student) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.city = city;
            this.mobileno = mobileno;
            this.student = student;
        }
    
    
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }
    
        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }
    
        public long getMobileno() {
            return mobileno;
        }
    
        public void setMobileno(long mobileno) {
            this.mobileno = mobileno;
        }
    
        public Student getStudent() {
            return student;
        }
    
        public void setStudent(Student student) {
            this.student = student;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Details [id=" + id + ", city=" + city + ", mobileno=" + mobileno + ", student=" + student + "]";
        }   
    }
```

> the Student.java class

```
 Student.java
    /*****************/
    package com.rest.entity;
    
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    
    @Entity
    public class Student {
    
        @Id
        private int id;
        
        private String name;
        
        private int clas;
        
        public Student() {
            
        }
    
    
        public Student(int id, String name, int clas) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.clas = clas;
        }
    
    
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public int getClas() {
            return clas;
        }
    
        public void setClas(int clas) {
            this.clas = clas;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", clas=" + clas + "]";
        }
        
        
    }
```

> the DetailsService layer

```
 DetailsServImpl.java
    /*******************/
    package com.rest.service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
    
    import com.rest.entity.Details;
    @Service
    public class DetailsServImpl implements DetailsServ {
    
        
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
        private String crmRestUrl;
            
        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        
        @Autowired
        public DetailsServImpl(RestTemplate theRestTemplate, 
                @Value("${crm.rest.url}") String theUrl) {
            restTemplate = theRestTemplate;
            crmRestUrl = theUrl;
                    
            logger.info("Loaded property:  crm.rest.url=" + crmRestUrl);
        }
        
        
        @Override
        public List<Details> getDetails() {
            logger.info("in getDetails(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
    
            // make REST call
            ResponseEntity<List<Details>> responseEntity = 
                                                restTemplate.exchange(crmRestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, 
                                                                      new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Details>>() {});
    
            // get the list of customers from response
            List<Details> theDetails = responseEntity.getBody();
    
            logger.info("in getDetails(): details" + theDetails);
            return theDetails;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Details getDetails(int theId) {
            logger.info("in getDetails(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
    
            // make REST call
            Details theDetails = 
                    restTemplate.getForObject(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId, 
                                              Details.class);
    
            logger.info("in saveDetails(): theDetails=" + theDetails);
            
            return theDetails;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void saveDetails(Details theDetails) {
    logger.info("in saveSt(): Cudentalling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
            
            int detailsId = theDetails.getId();
    
            // make REST call
            if (detailsId == 0) {
                // add employee
                restTemplate.postForEntity(crmRestUrl, theDetails, String.class);           
            
            } else {
                // update employee
                restTemplate.put(crmRestUrl, theDetails);
            }
    
            logger.info("in saveDetails(): success");
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void deleteDetails(int theId) {
            logger.info("in deleteDetails(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
    
            // make REST call
            restTemplate.delete(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId);
    
            logger.info("in deleteDetails(): deleted Details theId=" + theId);
    
        }
    
    }
```

> StudentService layer

```
StudentServImpl.java
/***************************/
package com.rest.service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.rest.entity.Details;
import com.rest.entity.Student;
@Service
public class StudentServImpl implements StudentServ {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String crmRestUrl;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    @Autowired
    public StudentServImpl(RestTemplate theRestTemplate,@Value("${crm.rest.url}") String theUrl){
        restTemplate = theRestTemplate;
        crmRestUrl = theUrl;
        logger.info("Loaded property:  crm.rest.url=" + crmRestUrl);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Student> getStudent() {
        logger.info("in getCustomers(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        ResponseEntity<List<Student>> responseEntity = 
                                            restTemplate.exchange(crmRestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, 
                                                                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Student>>() {});

        // get the list of customers from response
        List<Student> theStudent = responseEntity.getBody();
        logger.info("in getCustomers(): customers" + theStudent);
        return theStudent;
    }
    @Override
    public void saveStudent(Student theStudent) {
logger.info("in saveSt(): Cudentalling REST API " + crmRestUrl);    

        
        int studentId = theStudent.getId();
        // make REST call
        if (studentId == 0) {
            // add employee
            restTemplate.postForEntity(crmRestUrl, theStudent, String.class);           
        
        } else {
            // update employee
            restTemplate.put(crmRestUrl, theStudent);
        }
        logger.info("in saveStudent(): success");       
    }
    @Override
    public Student getStudent(int theId) {
        logger.info("in getCustomer(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
        // make REST call
        Student theStudent = 
                restTemplate.getForObject(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId, 
                                          Student.class);
        logger.info("in saveCustomer(): theCustomer=" + theStudent);
        return theStudent;
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(int theId) {
        logger.info("in deleteStudent(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
        // make REST call
        restTemplate.delete(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId);
        logger.info("in deleteStudent(): deleted Student theId=" + theId);
    }
}
```

->In this controller class when updating and deleting are not working.
when we update it returns an empty row . and when we delete it throw an error. This the Single controller class for multiple entites of OneToOne relation.

```
 ClientController.java
/****************************/
package com.rest.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.rest.entity.Details;
import com.rest.entity.Student;
import com.rest.service.DetailsServ;
import com.rest.service.StudentServ;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cont")
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private DetailsServ detailsServ;
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentServ studentServ;
    
    @GetMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel){
        Details theDetails = new Details(); 
        Student theStudent = new Student();
        theDetails.setStudent(theStudent);
        theModel.addAttribute("for",theDetails);
        return "the-for";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveForm")
    private String saveForm(@ModelAttribute("for") Details theDetails) {
        detailsServ.saveDetails(theDetails);
        return "redirect:/cont/list";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String showList(Model theModel) {
        List<Details> theDetails = detailsServ.getDetails();
        theModel.addAttribute("details", theDetails);
        return "list-table";
    }
    @GetMapping("/update")
    public String updateDetails(@RequestParam("detailsId") int theId, Model theModel) {
        Details theDetails =detailsServ.getDetails(theId);
        theModel.addAttribute("for",theDetails);
        return "the-for";
    }
    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteDetails(@RequestParam("detailsId") int theId) {
        
        detailsServ.deleteDetails(theId);
        return "redirect:/cont/list";
    }
```

> this one is the form to add or update details.

```
 the-for.jsp
    /************/
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
     <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> 
     <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%> 
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Save Customer</title>
    
        <link type="text/css"
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
    
        <link type="text/css"
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/add-customer-style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <h2>Form</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="container">
            <h3>Save StudentDetails</h3>
        
            <form:form action="saveForm" modelAttribute="for" method="POST">
    
                <!-- need to associate this data with customer id -->
                <form:hidden path="id" />
                        
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>City name:</label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="city" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>mobileno:</label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="mobileno" /></td>
                        </tr>
    
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>name:</label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="student.name" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>class:</label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="student.clas" /></td>
                        </tr>
    
                        <tr>
                            <td><label></label></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" /></td>
                        </tr>
    
                    
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            
            
            </form:form>
        
            <div style="clear; both;"></div>
            
            <p>
                <a href="list">Back to List</a>
            </p>
        
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
    
            
        }
```

> here this one is total CRUD page to display.

```
 list-table.jsp
    /*****************/
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
     <%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %> 
    
     
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
    <head>
    <title>List</title>
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
    
            <h2 class="pt-2">Student Manager</h2>
    
            <!-- put new button: Add Student -->
    
            <input type="button" value="Add Student"
                onclick="window.location.href='showForm'; return false;"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3" />
    
            <!--  add our html table here -->
    
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    
                <thead class="table-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>city</th>
                        <th>mobileno</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>class</th>
                        <th>Action</th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
    
                <!-- loop over and print our students -->
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="tempDetails" items="${details}">
    
             <!-- construct an "update" link with student id -->
                        <c:url var="updateLink" value="/cont/update"> 
                            <c:param name="detailsId" value="${tempDetails.id}" /> 
                        </c:url> 
    
                    <!-- construct an "delete" link with student id -->
                        <c:url var="deleteLink" value="/student/delete"> 
                            <c:param name="studentId" value="${tempStudent.id}" /> 
                        </c:url> 
    
                        <tr>
                            
                            <td>${tempDetails.city}</td>
                            <td>${tempDetails.mobileno}</td>
                            <td>${tempDetails.student.name}</td> 
                            <td>${tempDetails.student.clas}</td> 
                            
                            <td>
                                <!-- display the update link --> 
                                <a href="${updateLink}">Update</a> 
                                            |
                                 <a href="${deleteLink}" 
                                onclick="if (!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?'))) return false">Delete</a>
                            </td>
    
                        </tr>
    
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
    
            </table>
    
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: share your StudentController mapping against delete request.

Comment: Could you please include any code or errors as text, instead of as images? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes bro,I am used only single controller class ClientController.java, Bro for clerity I used @OneToOne relationship . Link of backend Rest CRUD :: (    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WX6yKN4jQnJnxE7KIkF94ue57hHOiICp/view?usp=sharing    )   Link of preasent front end client (    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WX6yKN4jQnJnxE7KIkF94ue57hHOiICp/view?usp=sharing  ). help me bro, thanks in advance

Comment: Error says, your code is trying to call api `/restclient/student/delete` but delete function in `ClientController` is mapped to api `/const/delete'.

Comment: So bro what should i do now, can please tell me

Comment: Link of backend side rest CRUD : ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WX6yKN4jQnJnxE7KIkF94ue57hHOiICp/view?usp=sharing )   Link of client side rest CRUD ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-hlfTtumPYWTdWhyOTjnBgALVgduB9PB/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: Please don't use external links to show your code, as they are not guaranteed to be static and are not always accessible by all readers. Instead, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the specific code you're having issues with.